# Specify Routing on Index Alias's Term Lookup Filter

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using **Logstash**, **ElasticSearch** and **Kibana** to allow multiple users to log in and view the log data they have forwarded. I have created index aliases for each user. These restrict their results to contain only their own data.

I'd like to assign users to groups, and allow users to view data for the computers in their group. I created a parent-child relationship between the groups and the users, and I created a term lookup filter on the alias.

My problem is, I receive a `RoutingMissingException` when I try to apply the alias.

Is there a way to specify the routing for the term lookup filter? How can I lookup terms on a parent document?

I posted the mapping and alias below, but a full gist recreation is available at this [link](https://gist.github.com/cvializ/11294031).

```json
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/accesscontrol/' -d '{
    "mappings" : {
        "group" : {
            "properties" : {
                "name" : { "type" : "string" },
                "hosts" : { "type" : "string" }
            }
        },
        "user" : {
            "_parent" : { "type" : "group" },
            "_routing" : { "required" : true, "path" : "group_id" },
            "properties" : {
                "name" : { "type" : "string" },
                "group_id" : { "type" : "string" }
            }
        }
    }
}'

# Create the logstash alias for cvializ
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "logstash-2014.04.25", "alias" : "cvializ-logstash-2014.04.25" } },
        { 
            "add" : { 
                "index" : "logstash-2014.04.25",
                "alias" : "cvializ-logstash-2014.04.25",
                "routing" : "intern",
                "filter": {
                    "terms" : {
                        "host" : {
                            "index" : "accesscontrol",
                            "type" : "user",
                            "id" : "cvializ",
                            "path" : "group.hosts"
                        },
                        "_cache_key" : "cvializ_hosts"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In attempting to find a workaround for this error, I [submitted a bug](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/6110) to the ElasticSearch team, and received an answer from them. It was a bug in ElasticSearch where the filter is applied before the dynamic mapping, causing some erroneous output. I've included their workaround below:

```
PUT /accesscontrol/group/admin
{
    "name" : "admin",
    "hosts" : ["computer1","computer2","computer3"]
}


PUT /_template/admin_group
{
    "template" : "logstash-*",
    "aliases" : {        
        "template-admin-{index}" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "host" : {
                        "index" : "accesscontrol",
                        "type" : "group",
                        "id" : "admin",
                        "path" : "hosts"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "example" : {
        "properties": {
          "host" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }  
        } 
      }
    }
}


POST /logstash-2014.05.09/example/1
{
    "message":"my sample data",
    "@version":"1",
    "@timestamp":"2014-05-09T16:25:45.613Z",
    "type":"example",
    "host":"computer1"
}


GET /template-admin-logstash-2014.05.09/_search
```